# Python: Iterate through string and print only specific words

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm taking a class in python and now I'm struggling to complete one of the tasks.

The aim is to ask for an input, integrate through that string and print only words that start with letters > g. If the word starts with a letter larger than g, we print that word. Otherwise, we empty the word and iterate through the next word(s) in the string to do the same check.

This is the code I have, and the output. Would be grateful for some tips on how to solve the problem.

```
        # [] create words after "G" following the Assignment requirements use of functions, menhods and kwyowrds
        # sample quote "Wheresoever you go, go with all your heart" ~ Confucius (551 BC - 479 BC)
        # [] copy and paste in edX assignment page

        quote = input("Enter a sentence: ")
        word = ""

        # iterate through each character in quote
        for char in quote:

            # test if character is alpha
            if char.isalpha():
                word += char 

            else:


                if word[0].lower() >= "h":
                    print(word.upper())   

                else:
                    word=""

    Enter a sentence: Wheresoever you go, go with all your heart
    WHERESOEVER
    WHERESOEVERYOU
    WHERESOEVERYOUGO
    WHERESOEVERYOUGO
    WHERESOEVERYOUGOGO
    WHERESOEVERYOUGOGOWITH
    WHERESOEVERYOUGOGOWITHALL
    WHERESOEVERYOUGOGOWITHALLYOUR



The output should look like,

Sample output:
WHERESOEVER
YOU
WITH
YOUR
HEART
```

Comment: First, if your teacher hasn’t banned all use of explicit string methods, start with `quote.split()`. Then you can iterate over words instead of iterating over characters and trying to rebuild the words on the fly.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @smb564 Where did he say he was getting an error? He showed the expected output and the actual output, and they’re obviously different.

Comment: The problem with your existing code is that you never set `word=‘’` again after using it, so you just keep appending to the same word (and that also means `word[0]` is always `’W’`). The problem spec even says “empty the word”; you just left out that part. You should be able to figure out where to add it in your code.

Comment: ... although I suppose that is a good meaning for “integrate through the string” instead of just iterating through it. This is basically a discrete integral of the string. :)

Answer (score 3):

Simply a list comprehension with `split` will do:

```
s = "Wheresoever you go, go with all your heart"
print(' '.join([word for word in s.split() if word[0].lower() > 'g']))
# Wheresoever you with your heart
```

Modifying to match with the desired output (Making all uppercase and on new lines):

```
s = "Wheresoever you go, go with all your heart"
print('\n'.join([word.upper() for word in s.split() if word[0].lower() > 'g']))

'''
WHERESOEVER 
YOU 
WITH 
YOUR 
HEART
'''
```

**Without** list comprehension:

```
s = "Wheresoever you go, go with all your heart"
for word in s.split():  # Split the sentence into words and iterate through each.
    if word[0].lower() > 'g':  # Check if the first character (lowercased) > g.
        print(word.upper())  # If so, print the word all capitalised.
```

Comment: Look at the desired output. You didn’t uppercase the words, or print each one on its own line. Anyone who can understand this code well enough to submit it for a homework answer should be able to figure out on his own how to do that, but you should probably mention in the answer that he’ll need to do so.

Comment: Might want to unravel that to a *full* for loop and add that to the answer for the OP who is a struggling student.

Comment: @wwii Do you mean a non list comprehension version?

Comment: @ZhekaKoval Filtering punctuation characters is not at all necessary as OP haven't specified anything about that anywhere in the question. Or if he wants to do so, you made a great answer and he may refer to yours. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "Wheresoever you go, go with all your heart"
out = s.translate(str.maketrans(string.punctuation, " "*len(string.punctuation)))
desired_result = [word.upper() for word in out.split() if word and word[0].lower() > 'g']
print(*desired_result, sep="\n")
```

Comment: This doesn’t match the desired output. And, since you discarded the order (and any dups) when you used a set for storage, there’s no way to recover the desired output.

Comment: I guess that word ordering as well as word case, has to be preserved in the answer wanted by the teacher. This is not the case here.

Comment: Also, what do you have against comprehensions? A setcomp instead of map would let you remove that `set` call and that lambda, making the code shorter and more readable and probably more efficient to boot.

Comment: @abarnert fixed

Comment: @sciroccorics fixed

Answer (score 0):

Here is a readable and commented solution. The idea is first to split the sentence into a list of words using `re.findall` (regex package) and iterate through this list, instead of iterating on each character as you did. It is then quite easy to print only the words starting by a letter greater then 'g':

```
import re

# Prompt for an input sentence
quote = input("Enter a sentence: ")

# Split the sentence into a list of words
words = re.findall(r'\w+', quote)

# Iterate through each word
for word in words:
    # Print the word if its 1st letter is greater than 'g'
    if word[0].lower() > 'g':
        print(word.upper())
```

To go further, here is also the one-line style solution based on exactly the same logic, using list comprehension:

```
import re

# Prompt for an input sentence
quote = input("Enter a sentence: ")

# Print each word starting by a letter greater than 'g', in upper case
print(*[word.upper() for word in re.findall(r'\w+', quote) if word[0].lower() > 'g'], sep='\n')
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that you're only resetting `word` to an empty string in the `else` clause.  You need to reset it to an empty string immediately after the `print(word.upper())` statement as well for the code as you've wrote it to work correctly.

That being said, if it's not explicitly disallowed for the class you're taking, you should look into string methods, specifically `string.split()`

Comment: He doesn’t want a function in the string module. If you’re just going to copy the comments into an answer, at least get it right.